# JWT signature does not match locally computed signature

Tags: java, jwt, token

I am using

```
JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder()
                    .setId(user.getEmail())
                    .signWith(signatureAlgorithm, signingKey);
```

to create a token then

```
Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parse(token);
```

to authenticate.  When I run this in a JUnit test, it works fine.  However, when I authenticate token passed as a header over REST call, authentication fails with SignatureException.  I have verified the token on both ends of the HTTP call and the token string is identical.  Code to create/authenticate is static, therefore, the secret is same on each side.

Comment: Could you post an example token and the secret key?

Comment: static Key secret = MacProvider.generateKey(); 
SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;
byte[] apiKeySecretBytes = secret.getEncoded();
Key signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(apiKeySecretBytes, signatureAlgorithm.getJcaName());

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`static Key secret = MacProvider.generateKey();` will generate a new random key each time your server is reloaded because static variables are initialized when the class is loaded

It means that if you issue a JWT, it is only valid as long as the server does not reboot. The `SignatureException` you got is because the signing key it is different

You need to store the signing key `secret.getEncoded()` after first generation and load it when your module starts

Comment: Great observation.  However, I have a single utility class on the server that is the only reference to this static Key.  It uses this single reference for both create and authenticate operations.  This is why it is so confusing.

Comment: Just to check that there is no other hidden problem: could you print the key content before signing and verification? E.g `System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(secret.getEncoded()))`

Comment: @stanlick, Did you check if the secret code was the same when signing and verifying?

Comment: you nailed it brother!  It was an issue with two different VM's.  Even though the token generated was exactly the same on both ends, the verification was failing because token wasn't generated on the same VM that was performing verification

Comment: I have similar problem? Could you tell me how to resolve it?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45142800/spring-spock-integration-test-of-authentication

Answer (score 13):

I have had the same problem, I noticed that in sources whenever they convert the signing key they explicitly specify UTF-8 encoding. I tried changing the encoding while both decoding the token:

```
 private Jws<Claims> decodeToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(securityProperties.getTokenSecret().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
                .parseClaimsJws(token);
 }
```

And when signing the token:

```
private String getSignedToken(UserDetailsAdapter user, List<String> roles, byte[] signingKey) {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(signingKey), SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)
                .setHeaderParam("typ", securityProperties.getTokenType())
                .setIssuer(guiServerSecurityProperties.getTokenIssuer())
                .setAudience(guiServerSecurityProperties.getTokenAudience())
                .setSubject(user.getUsername())
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 864000000))
                .claim("rol", roles)
                .compact();
    }
```

This is the only thing that fixed this for me.

Comment: this worked for me : 
 Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))).parse(token);

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem. In my case it was wrong token validation. I set sign as bytes:

```
.signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtConfig.getSecret().getBytes())
```

But when i was parsing the token and setting signKey i setted it as a String, not as bytes:

```
Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(signingKey).parseClaimsJws(this.token)
```

Also always check quotes and spaces when checking token, there often can be excess space/quote in the start/end of the token (use trim() method)

Comment: this was precisely the problem in my case. Thanks.

Comment: final String user =
          Jwts.parser()
              .setSigningKey(secret.getBytes())
              .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
              .getBody()
              .getSubject();

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem. In my case both keys were the same, but for some reason I was receiving a token within quotes (e.g `"Syasda.da3das.aDjty6"` instead of just `Syasda.da3das.aDjty6`).

It took me quite some time to realize this since most of the time while testing on jwt.io I would just copy the token manually without the brackets to verify it.

```
token = token.replace("\"","");
```

Removing those quotes solved the problem for me. Hopefully this will help someone else as well.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem modifying the HOST in the URL REST endpoint. It had a wrong host which was returned error HTTP 401 unauthorized.

Answer (score 1):

Two types of problems meight exists:

1. `Key key = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256);` generates a different random key each time the function `secretKeyFor` is run. So if you want to generate a constant key, try this one

```
 public SecretKey generalKey(){
        String stringKey = Global.JWT_SECRET;
        byte[] encodedKey =Base64.decodeBase64(stringKey);
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, 0, encodedKey.length,
                "HmacSHA512");
        return key;
    }
```

2. In my code, I recieve the token transferred by ajax, and JSON.stringify() is used to convert the javasript object to string, which wrapped additional quota on the origin string, try to eliminate the quota as [Nuper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56193290/8987062) said.

Answer (score 0):

When I was selecting "JWT Bearer" as Authorization in Postman, I was providing the generated JWT token as a secret. So, Postman itself was generating a new JWT token and was sending it to my application. This token was not a valid token and hence the authentication was failing.

To resolve it, I choose "No Auth" in the Authorization and manually added the header "Authorization: Bearer " in a simple curl command and then I was able to access the endpoint.

In the Authentication filter, I am reading "Authorization" field from request header, that is why I added this header in the request.

In short, I was not able to send request correctly from Postman and hence it was not working but when I send it correctly using CURL command and then later by postman also, it started working.

If in your request, your token is getting changed then we will get this issue.